# Dynamically defined Function-type vars

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I am trying to extend a UIKit class (which I can't edit normally) by creating a new function and a new Function-type variable, which is going to use ObjC Runtime to make it look&feel like a stored property.

```
extension UITextField {

    private struct DynamicallyDefinedVars {
        static var oneVar = "oneVar"
    }

    var oneVar: ((String?)->Bool)? {
        get{
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &DynamicallyDefinedVars.oneVar) as? (String?)->Bool
        }
        set{
            if let newValue: AnyObject = newValue {
                objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &DynamicallyDefinedVars.oneVar, newValue, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
            }
        }
    }

    func callTheVarFunc() -> Bool {
        if let oneVar = oneVar {
            return oneVar("Foo")
        }

        return true
    }
}
```

What I hope to achieve:

```
var foo: UITextField

foo.oneVar = { (bar: String?) -> Bool in
  return true
}

if foo.callTheVarFunc {
  doSomething
}
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
Cannot convert value of type '((String?) -> Bool)?' to specified type 'AnyObject?'
```

It would work fine if oneVar was typed something like String or an array of sorts, but I see the Function Types are not included in AnyObject, thus giving me issues when trying to objc_setAssociatedObject. Any thoughts on how I can get the desired behaviour (through extensions, without subclassing)? Each instance has to have a different oneVar value to be used with the callTheVarFunc function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just seen this problem, in Swift **closures** cannot be casted to **AnyObject** so you can workaround this annoying thing creating a custom class:

```
extension UITextField {

    class CustomClosure {
        var closure: ((String?)->Bool)?

        init(_ closure: ((String?)->Bool)?) {
            self.closure = closure
        }
    }

    private struct DynamicallyDefinedVars {
        static var oneVar = "oneVar"
    }

    var oneVar: ((String?)->Bool)? {
        get{
            if let cl = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &DynamicallyDefinedVars.oneVar) as? CustomClosure {
             return cl.closure
            }
        return nil
        }
        set{
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &DynamicallyDefinedVars.oneVar,CustomClosure(newValue), .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
        }
    }

    func callTheVarFunc() -> Bool {
        if let oneVar = oneVar {
            return oneVar("Foo")
        }

        return true
    }
}
```